# What book did Kirk receive at the end of the TOS episode "Court Martial"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In the TOS episode [Court Martial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Court_Martial_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)), Kirk's defense lawyer Samuel T. Cogley has a preference for books over computers.  In one of the last scenes Kirk is gifted a book by Cogley (but physically handed over by Lt. Areel Shaw, Kirk's former lover and also his prosecutor in this case).  While Shaw describes it as not being a first edition or anything special, it obviously has enough importance that Cogley wants Kirk to have it.

What was the book that Cogley gifted to Kirk?

Comment: It's just "a book". Cogley wants him to read something not off of a screen

Comment: I remember that the first time it was aired, I also remember thinking "well? What's the book?"

Comment: @DannyMcG - "*Sam Cogley asked me to give you something special. It's not a first edition, **just a book. Sam says that makes it special.***".

Comment: During his academy days, Kirk was described as having been “a stack of books with legs.”  We also know that he likes actual printed books; he has several in his cabin,  as can be seen in more than one episode.  So a printed book would be a very appropriate gift for him.

IMDB notes that “Court Martial” is similar to “Sherlock Holmes: The Adventure of the Norwood Builder” (see the trivia section under this episode’s listing there) but that's hardly canonical evidence to suggest that this was the book.